# Content Query Web Part: additional filters do not load checkbox column

Tags: content-query-web-part

Background: I just migrated a site collection from SP2010 to SP2013. There is a custom content type "News" defined. The content type seems migrated without issue.

In the "News" content type there is a custom column "Hot news" with type Yes/No. My requirement is to setup a Content Query Web Part to show everything content type=News with column "Hot news=Yes".

So in the CQWP I choose Content Type=News. In additional filter I choose Hot news, is equal to, [Yes]. It didn't work. I have tried Yes, 1, etc all the same.

Then I reset all query in CQWP. In the source field I chooose the library using "News" content type. This time in the additioanl filter I choose Hot news. The filter immediately show up two radio Yes and No.

May I know how can I query entire site collection for content type=News with column "Hot news" = Yes?